# PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID returns blank when sending message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing add-in for Outlook 2013,I'm struggling with PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID , I could easily get PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID on archiving incoming mails, but it returns nothing on sending mail.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you! 
here is my code

```
 string PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyAccessor pal = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
        string Internet_Message_Id = pal.GetProperty(PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

That property is only sent after the message is sent. Exchange 2010/2013 sets that property for all messages created in the store, but you will not necessarily see it on messages in the cached store.
Are you using PST or Exchange?

Comment: Im using Exchange and I can see that property blank when I sent message and then save the mail in database.

Comment: You will not see that property in a cached store. Do you see the property if you turn the cached mode off?

Comment: Thank you very much. I turn off cache mode, I got that property, but is there any way to get that property while sending mail , because I need that property value to check whether email is archived before or not.