# Get Message-ID after send mail

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-redemption

For my outlook addin I need to handle emails, calculate an *unique* hash and store this hash on a server/database. For example :

**There are 4 users :**

- user1@company.com
- user2@company.com
- user3@company.com
- randomperson@gmail.com

**Case 1:**

*User1* sends a mail to *User2* and *User3*. *User2* wants to store the mailhash serverside, so he clicks an addin button. A hash is calculated with code like this

```
var accessor = mailItem.PropertyAccessor;
var subject = accessor.GetProperty(_PR_SUBJECT_W_TAG).ToString();
var messageId  = accessor.GetProperty(_PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG).ToString();
var hash = CalulateHash(subject + messageId);
```

This hash is stored on the server. If *User3* tries to store the hash of the mail too, he gets the same hash (cause subject and messageid should be the same ==> [rfc822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z8)) and the server knows, he got this hash already. This works very well.

**Case 2:**
*User1* wants to send a mail to *User2*,*User3* and *randomperson*. Cause *randomperson* doesn't belong to their company, *User1* want to use the function `SendAndStore()`. Before the mail is send, a custom property is added to the new mail

```
mailItem.UserProperties.Add("HandleAfterSent", MSOutlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
var aasProp = mailItem.UserProperties.Find("HandleAfterSent");
if (aasProp != null)
{
    aasProp.Value = "some_value";
}
mailItem.Save();

SendMailItem(mailItem);
```

Moreover, there is a possibility to get notified if a new item is added to a inboxfolder. So I observe the **sent** folder.

```
inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(MSOutlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
items = inbox.Items;
items.ItemAdd += OnInboxItemAdded;
```

If the mail is send via `SendMailItem(mailItem);`, the handler is called (works fine too). But unfortunately I have problems with calculating the hash of the send mail, cause this mail has no Message-ID. Does anyone have a idea, how to get the Message-ID of a mail, which was send just now.
I already tried to set the Message-ID on my own, but it is overriden from MS Exchange server.

EDIT :
Outlook is on cache mode. I need a possibility to get the Message-ID for this scenario too.

EDIT2 (in addition to comments) :
**Case 3:**
*randomperson* wants to send a mail to *User1*,*User2* and *User3*. Cause *randomperson* doesn't belong to their company, *User1* want to use the function `StoreFromInbox()`. Mails in the inbox of all three Users have the same Message-ID. But they have different _PR_SEARCH_KEY_ , so we can't use this property.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029082/pr-internet-message-id-returns-blank-when-sending-message

Comment: Thats relevant,you're right. Without cache mode it works. But is there a possibility to get the id on cache mode too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `PR_SEARCH_KEY` MAPI property - it should stay the same after the message is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.

Comment: should I use it as value for the hash code? I changed some code to use more redemption functions. but currently I got an exception when using `rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(outlookMailItem.EntryID, outlookMailItem.Parent.StoreID, 0x200) as IRDOMail;`. I hoped to get the message id with this code even in cached mode

Comment: damn outlook cache. if I use a timer and call `rdoSession.GetMessageFromID(outlookMailItem.EntryID, outlookMailItem.Parent.StoreID, 0x200) as IRDOMail;` about one minute after sending the mail, there is no exception. is there any other solution instead of waiting?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not - just hash the value of PR_SEARCH_KEY. Why are you reopening the item by its entry id?

Comment: I added a new EDIT on the question. PR_SEARCH_KEY is not unique, if a external mail was received (Recipient User1 found another value than Recipient User2), so this isn't a possible property to calculate a hash. What's the difference between PR_SEARCH_KEY and PR_SENDER_SEARCH_KEY ?

Comment: If a message is sent, of course PR_SEARCH_KEY will be different on the recipient's side.